# What is the classifier for a piece of ginger?

Tags: vocabulary

My French friend told me that he had to chop up 20 gingers at work. He works in a restaurant.

I told him it sounded funny and a classifier is required.

It got me thinking, what is the classifier or counting word for ginger?

I’m referring to the funny shaped lump of knotty root, not the ground up or chopped up form.

For example 20 heads of cabbage, 20 sticks of celery etc.

I suppose you could say 20 ginger roots, but what about 20 roots of ginger?

Is there another term I’m overlooking?

Comment: What's wrong with "20 ginger roots"?

Comment: Few of us work with twenty red-heads, let alone ones we'd take an axe to. Perhaps you want pieces of ginger root?

Comment: Did a quick check on https://cooking.stackexchange.com/search?q=ginger. I'm seeing "ginger slice," "ginger knob," and "ginger piece." Since your friend is a restaurateur, perhaps this question should be evaluated by foodies?

Comment: Note that it is 20 *stalks* of celery, not sticks, though the latter would be understood.

Comment: This should probably be on cooking.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each piece of ginger is a bulbous protrusion from the root, you could call it a *knob* of ginger.

In the sentence it would be:
*"My French friend told me that he had to chop up 20 knobs of ginger at work."*

Comment: I don't know if this is a playful answer, but the word knob has a different connotation in common English use, and this sentence would often raise a smile.

Comment: Fully aware of the other connotation. However, this is also used in common English to describe *a small quantity of butter*, *a rotary switch*, etc. Taking the *small quantity of butter* example, one can begin to see why this is also used for ginger.

Comment: That was the answer that occurred to me as well, and I think I've seen it used in recipes.

Comment: Would that be *chopping up 20 ginger knobs* ? Maybe a *nub* would be better.

Comment: *knobs of ginger* is what I hear used more frequently.

Comment: @Jonathan Moore - I think 'knob' meaning 'penis', and 'stupid man' are mainly British usages.